# Efficient coding with python and numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm reading a reference [1] on data analysis with python and testing the code in my laptop. The text discusses how using numpy arrays can speed up things as compared to using built-in lists instead.

I'm surprised, however, by getting right the opposite results:

```
In [5]: L =range(10000000); %timeit sum(L)
1 loops, best of 3: 201 ms per loop

In [9]: xL=np.array(L,dtype=int); %timeit sum(xL)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.79 s per loop
```

The first sum is supposed to be much slower than the second. Changing the `dtype` option value doesn't change the result.

I'm using ipython (2.4.0) notebook with Firefox on a OSX 10.6.8. Maybe a problem with my (old) version of python/OS?

[1] "*Statistics, Data Mining and Machine Learning in Astronomy: A Practical Python for the Survey of Data*", Zeljko Ivezic et al., Princeton Univ. Press 2014. Appendix A.8.

Comment: I apologize for such a dump question. I should have been more careful when copying the code. I'm not sure if I should delete this question, after having gotten two correct answers though.

Comment: @unutbu , wim, you both have high enough a reputation for not changing much if I delete my question (I guess that would remove the reputation you gained here). Honestly, I think this question of mine just contributes to the noise in here.

Comment: MASL I think your question is fine, there is no such thing as dump questions.  Only dumb questions.

Comment: :) And that too! Definitely not the right day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the NumPy array's [`sum` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), not the plain Python [builtin `sum` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), in order to take advantage of NumPy:

```
In [32]: L =range(10000000)

In [33]: %timeit sum(L)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.4 ms per loop

In [34]: xL=np.array(L,dtype=int)

In [35]: %timeit xL.sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.49 ms per loop
```

Comment: Arg! My bad!  I should have been more careful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're using the python `sum` on the numpy array instead of numpy's sum:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L = range(10000000)
>>> timeit sum(L)
10 loops, best of 3: 69.9 ms per loop
>>> xL = np.array(L, dtype=int)
>>> timeit sum(xL)
1 loops, best of 3: 715 ms per loop
```

Slooooow!  Here's the 10x speedup:

```
>>> timeit xL.sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 7.34 ms per loop
>>> timeit np.sum(xL)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.38 ms per loop
```